# Migrating application from websphere to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, websphere, tomcat6, estimation

I will be migrating a websphere application to tomcat. I've read these online docs - http://blogs.mulesoft.org/how-to-migrate-your-weblogic-or-websphere-app-to-tomcat/ & 
http://www.mulesoft.com/downloads/Migrating-from-Websphere-to-Tomcat-Mulesoft.pdf

I also found this helpful - [What are the differences when deploying on Tomcat vs. Websphere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520293/what-are-the-differences-when-deploying-on-tomcat-vs-websphere)

From reading these docs it seems like it's a not too difficult task, at least on the face of it. So any J2ee/EE functionality that the app is using which tomcat does not implement needs to be added manually, this may include changes to the code base to support the tomcat server.

2. Are there any technical details/pitfalls I should watch out for during migration?
3. How can I effectively estimate the amount of time this migration should take ?

Comment: First - you must tell if you're using such things as: EJB or WebSphere-managed security. If it is hust a WAR it should be easy.

Comment: To add to  Grzegorz comments ensure that any WebSphere specific extensions are not being used in the application. You would be surprised that heaps of people tend to do this (without any careful consideration) and come migration time - people are clueless on how to remove such dependencies.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is dependent on the organisation itself. Comments above were helpful, maybe put the comments into a answers so I can accept/upvote ?

Comment: @blue-sky, have you completed this migration , can you list down the steps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat is just servlet container and lacks most of the WAS features. For any feature you are missing you will have to expand tomcat functionality by adding stuff like transactional managers, jpa, ejb container, mail service....

So your task may or may be not hard to execute. It primary depends on your application (is it a webapp?) and your tomcat skills.

If you have a large Java EE application, and no experience in doing this, I would recommend to change your goal and instead target JBossAS, Glassfish or some other Java EE AS instead.